# What's wrong with this least common ancestor algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, least-common-ancestor

I was asked the following question in a job interview:

> Given a root node (to a well formed binary tree) and two other nodes (which are guaranteed to be in the tree, and are also distinct), return the lowest common ancestor of the two nodes.

I didn't know any least common ancestor algorithms, so I tried to make one on the spot. I produced the following code:

```
def least_common_ancestor(root, a, b):
    lca = [None]
    def check_subtree(subtree, lca=lca):
        if lca[0] is not None or subtree is None:
            return 0

        if subtree is a or subtree is b:
            return 1
        else:
            ans = sum(check_subtree(n) for n in (subtree.left, subtree.right))

        if ans == 2:
            lca[0] = subtree
            return 0

        return ans

    check_subtree(root)

    return lca[0]


class Node:
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

I tried the following test cases and got the answer that I expected:

```
a = Node(None, None)
b = Node(None, None)

tree = Node(Node(Node(None, a), b), None)
tree2 = Node(a, Node(Node(None, None), b))
tree3 = Node(a, b)
```

but my interviewer told me that "there is a class of trees for which your algorithm returns None." I couldn't figure out what it was and I flubbed the interview. I can't think of a case where the algorithm would make it to the bottom of the tree without `ans` ever becoming 2 -- what am I missing?

Comment: Now make `b` a sub-node of `a` or vice-versa.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, thank you, that's it. If you make that in to an answer I'd be happy to accept. Otherwise, maybe I should delete this question?

Comment: You seem to assume that a and b are in different subtrees of their lca. This is not a good assumption. Start with border cases. `a is b`, `a is root`, the tree only has left branches etc. You will be surprised.

Comment: @n.m.: the problem constraints say that both `a` and `b` are in the tree. In a binary search tree that means you can restrict yourself to the subtree that contains both nodes at each 'turn'; if you need to split up to the left and right child you have found your common ancestor..

Comment: @MartijnPieters "if you need to split up to the left and right child you have found your common ancestor" This is true, but the opposite is not. You need a condition that is both necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @n.m.: if both elements are in the tree, the current node is not one of them, and you don't have to split your search for both, then you just go down that one side that contains both nodes to continue the search. Since they are guaranteed to be contained in the tree, you will not encounter an empty child tree on that side.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What if the current node *is* one if them?

Comment: @n.m.: then that is the lowest common ancestor of both.

Comment: @MartijnPieters right, and it does *not* contain given nodes in different subtrees.

Comment: @n.m.: not following you there; I already handled the case of 'the current node is not one the two target nodes'.

Comment: I've lost you. You seem to favour the proposition that "a and b are in different subtrees of their lca", which I deem false. Is this true? If it is, do you think that this holds when a is a direct ancestor of b? If it is not true, what exactly are you disagreeing with?

Comment: @n.m.: I did not favour that proposition. I said that *if both elements are in the tree, **the current node is not one of them**, and you don't have to split your search for both* to qualify that you had to search one of the subtrees.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "I did not favour that proposition." You have responded to my comment that *only* suggested that this proposition is false, with something that looks like disagreement.

Comment: @n.m.: sorry, I am no longer following the double negatives here.

Comment: So this entire thread looks rather pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to account for the case where `a` is a direct ancestor of `b`, or vice versa. You stop searching as soon as you find either node and return `1`, so you'll never find the other node in that case.

You were given a *well-formed binary search tree*; one of the properties of such a tree is that you can easily find elements based on their relative size to the current node; smaller elements are going into the left sub-tree, greater go into the right. As such, if you know that *both elements* are in the tree you only need to compare keys; as soon as you find a node that is *in between* the two target nodes, or equal to one them, you have found lowest common ancestor.

Your sample nodes never included the keys stored in the tree, so you cannot make use of this property, but if you *did*, you'd use:

```
def lca(tree, a, b):
    if a.key <= tree.key <= b.key:
        return tree
    if a.key < tree.key and b.key < tree.key:
        return lca(tree.left, a, b)
    return lca(tree.right, a, b)
```

If the tree is merely a 'regular' binary tree, and not a search tree, your only option is to find the paths for both elements and find the point at which these paths diverge.

If your binary tree maintains *parent references* and *depth*, this can be done efficiently; simply walk up the deeper of the two nodes until you are at the same depth, then continue upwards from both nodes until you have found a common node; that is the least-common-ancestor.

If you don't have those two elements, you'll have to find the path to both nodes with separate searches, starting from the root, then find the last common node in those two paths.

Comment: The tree isn't guaranteed to be sorted, or have keys. I don't believe that "binary tree" implies "binary search tree."

Comment: @PatrickCollins: right, that is an important distinction. Were you allowed to annotate the nodes with depth?

Comment: The question as written at the top is the full prompt I was given. I later gave an answer that the interviewer identified as correct that involved building up a path from the root to `a` and from the root to `b`, then checking the intersection of that path.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: right; summarised your two options in those cases then. In interviews, it is fine to try and limit your problem further by asking questions. The interviewer might have let you contrain it to a BST, for example (but be prepared for it to be expanded to a wider class of problems anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the case where `a` is an ancestor of `b`.

Look at the simple counter example:

```
    a
  b  None
```

`a` is also given as `root`, and when invoking the function, you invoke `check_subtree(root)`, which is `a`, you then find out that this is what you are looking for (in the stop clause that returns 1), and return `1` immidiately without setting `lca` as it should have been.